# Efficient way to find Non-maximum suppression in images?

Tags: algorithm

```
 Let I be an image of integer pixel values, height h, width w.
 Let r be a strictly positive integer, We want to extract the positions (row, col) of the local maxima of the image, 
 where local means over a neighborhood of size 2r+1 x 2r+1.

 S = {(x,y), such that strict-argmax_N((x,y), r) I == (x, y)}
    where N((x,y), r) = square of side 2r+1 centered on (x,y).


 img:
 2 0 0 0 0
 1 2 3 0 8
 0 0 0 0 9
 r=1 => 3x3 neighborhoods
  => [(x,y), ...] = [(1, 2), (2, 4)]
```

Is there a better algorithm than O(h*w*r*r) ?

Answer (score 2):

2D local minimum and maximum filters can split into 1D filters, then apply alg

> A fast algorithm for local minimum and maximum filters on rectangular and octagonal kernels

basically for each 1D vector,

1. divided into sub-arrays (groups) of size k, with k the structuring size.
   [image]
2. construst 2 array g, h by:

[image]

3. the results is:
   [image]

---

for exmaple:
with filter size equal to 5, the local maximun of index `4` is maximun of `g[6]` and `h[2]`

Comment: This looks good for 1D sequences (linear time and space to construct, O(1) lookups with random access). How can the 2D image be split into 1D sequences? Also can it be adapted to find only unique maxima?

Comment: fisrt apply fast local alg to the row, then apply it o the column, maximun filter is separatable

Comment: Ah, clever! And likely much faster than mine, not only by a log(r) factor asymptotically, but also because it's all sequential/strided memory accesses. Still wondering about unique maxima though.

Comment: I think uniqueness can be detected within this framework: Make another function g'(x), which is false when x % k == 1 and otherwise equal to (f(x) < g(x-1) && g'(x-1)) || (f(x) == g(x-1)). Make a similar function h'(x) (for h()). Set H=h(x-(k-1)/2) and G=g(x+(k-1)/2). Then the max at x is duplicated iff G == H || G > H && g'(x+(k-1)/2) || H > G && h'(x-(k-1)/2).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in **O(w*h*log r) time**. (Due to constant factors, this might not be a win over the naive algorithm until r gets large.) First I'll describe how to find *some* maximum for each r*r window, then outline how to restrict to just unique maxima.

### Processing a w*r row in O(w*r) time

First, the maximum of an r*r square is the maximum of its r*1 column maxima, which you only need to compute once each even though each one is shared by up to r neighbourhoods (fewer at the edges).

To determine the maximum for the top-left r*r square, compute the vertical positions y[0], y[1], ..., y[r-1] of its r column maxima "the hard way", and insert each of them into a self-balancing binary search tree (BST) in which nodes are triples (p, u, v) maintained in increasing lexicographical order, where u is a row, v is a column and p is pix[u, v]. Reading the maximum (rightmost) value from this BST tells us the answer for this top-left r*r square. Given that we have processed all such topmost squares up to the one beginning in column c-1, to process the one beginning in column c:

1. Delete (pix[y[c-1], c-1], y[c-1], c-1) from the BST (amortised O(log r) time).
2. Compute the vertical position y[c+r-1] of the r*1 column maximum beginning at (0, c+r-1) "the hard way" (O(r) time).
3. Insert (pix[y[c+r-1], c+r-1], y[c+r-1], c+r-1) into the BST (amortised O(log r) time).
4. Read out the maximum (rightmost) value (p, u, v) from the BST (amortised O(log r) time): (u, v) is the location of some maximum within this r*r neighbourhood.

Repeat the above to process all r*r neighbourhoods along the top of the image. (Note that O(w(r + log r)) = O(wr).)

### Processing everything in O(w*h*log r) time

The whole image could be processed by repeating the above separately for each starting row, but that would result in an O(w*h*r)-time algorithm. We can shrink the r factor to log r.

For r*r neighbourhoods beginning at lower rows, it's not necessary to compute column maxima from scratch. We can use a similar approach to compute the location of the maximum of the r*1 block beginning at (u, v) from information about the r*1 block beginning at (u-1, v) in just O(log r) time. To do this, instead of just computing and storing, for each column c, the vertical location y[c] of the maximum in the r*1 block beginning at the current row, we can use self-balancing BSTs for these too, and use them to compute the y[] values as needed.

Specifically, for each column c = 0, 1, ..., w-1, we will keep a "column BST" CB[c] whose entries are pairs (p, u) maintained in increasing lexicographical order, where u is a row and p is pix[u, c]. When initially processing the top row of the image, for each column c, insert the r pairs into CB[c], and then read its largest (rightmost) leaf to obtain y[c]. Given that we have just processed all neighbourhoods beginning on row i-1, to process those beginning on row i, do the following for each column c:

1. Delete (pix[i-1, c], i-1) from CB[c] (amortised O(log r) time).
2. Insert (pix[i+r-1, c], i+r-1) into CB[c] (amortised O(log r) time).
3. Set y[c] to u, where (p, u) is the largest (rightmost) leaf in CB[c].

The above allows the O(r) step for calculating y[c+r-1] in the original procedure (step 2 there) to be sped up to O(log r).

### Finding unique maxima

If there are multiple maximal pixels in an r*r neighbourhood, then at least one of the following is true:

1. The second-highest column maximum is equal to the highest column maximum. This occurs when the maxima are in different columns
2. The column containing the highest column maximum contains it at least twice. This occurs when there are multiple maxima in a single column.

We can easily check these conditions in step 4 of the main algorithm, and suppress output for a neighbourhood if either of them hold, resulting in an algorithm that reports only unique maxima.

To check the first condition: After finding the maximum (p, u, v) in the BST, find the leaf that immediately precedes it in an inorder traversal (its "nearest left sibling"). Call this (p', u', v'). The first condition is satisfied if and only if p' = p. This takes O(log r) time.

To check the second condition: After finding the maximum (p, u, v) in the BST, look in CB[v] for its maximum (rightmost) leaf (which will necessarily be (p, u)), and its "nearest left sibling" (p', u'). The second condition is satisfied if and only if p' = p.